# Python- global name is not defined

Tags: python, django, forms, datefield

I have a Django project, in which I want to display a form to the user on a particular webpage. Some of the fields of the form should be automatically populated with information from the database.

At the moment, two of the 'text' fields on the form are automatically populated when the page first loads, however, the 'date' field is left blank.

If I click on the text area for the 'date' field, a little calendar appears as a sort of 'drop down', and I can view a single month at a time. If I select a day from whichever month, that date is then inserted into the text area of the 'date' field. However, if I then reload the page, although the text fields retain their value, the 'date' field is blank again...

I have a Python class called `DepositInfoForm`, which is defined in the `forms.py` file of my `projects` app. The class is defined with the following structure:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidateFrom):
    ...
    date_received = mDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ('amount_exc_vat', 'amount_inc_vat', 'date_received')

    def __init__(self, *args, &&kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
        try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None

        # This is the code I have tried adding:
        model.date_received = fields.date_received

        ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
        return super(DepositInfoForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

However, when I try to view the page that displays this form in the browser, I get a `nameError` that says:

> NameError at /project/6311/concept/
>
> > global name 'fields' is not defined

and the line it's complaining about is:

```
model.date_received = fields.date_received
```

If I remove the line of code I added, then the page will be displayed properly, however, the date value I enter will not be stored, so when I refresh the page, the date has disappeared- how can I ensure that the date I select is stored, so that when I refresh the page, the date value that I selected remains in that field on the form?

**Edit**

The HTML displaying the part of the form that I'm interested in is:

```
<div class="col-12 box">
        <div>
            <table class="right fixed m-t-md">
                <tr>
                    {% for hidden in deposit_form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{hidden}}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for field in deposit_form.visible_fields %}
                        <td class="p-r-md">{{field.label}}</td><td class="p-r-md">{{field}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <td><a class="email_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=7">Raise invoice</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Ok, so I added a `print` statement to the `__init__` method in the `DepositInfoForm` class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
    project = instance.project

    try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
    except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
    try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
    except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None
    # ERF(21/11/2016 @ 11:00) Add a 'try' for date_deposit_received
    try: date_received = MoonDateField(instance.date_received)
    except TypeError: date_received = None
    print "try: date_received is being run in projects/forms.py (line 1103): %s " % date_received


    initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
    initial={
                'received': project.deposit_received,
                'amount_exc_vat': amount_exc_vat,
                'amount_inc_vat': amount_inc_vat,
                #ERF(21/11/2016 @ 1130) Add 'date received' to the 'initial' values...
                #'date_received': date_received #date_received,
                }
    kwargs['initial'] = initial

    super(DepositInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['date_received'].widget.attrs.update({'data-original-value': self.initial['date_received'] or ''})
```

and when I now reload this page in my browser, the console displays the `print` statement saying:

> try: date_received is being run in projects/forms.py (line 1103): None

i.e. the reason that the 'date' value is not retained in the text field on my form is because it is not actually saved to the `date_received` variable when the date is selected...

Why is this, and how can I save the selected date to the variable/ class instance, so that it can be retrieved when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Maybe you should try with self.fields and self.model?

Comment: The form you have shown here doesn't contain that line anywhere, you should try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Apologies- there's a typo in my code there- I'll amend that now... the form does contain that line: if you look inside the class `DepositInfoForm` code, at the end of the `def __init__` method below my comment `# This is the code I have tried adding`

Comment: `fields` is neither in the scope of `DepositInfoForm.__init__` nor globally defined, hence the error. `Meta.fields` and `DepositInfoForm.Meta.fields` are defined, but I am not sure which you can access within the `__init__` method.

Comment: @madtyn , if I do that, I get an `AttributeError` that says: `DepositInfoForm' object has no attribute 'fields`

Comment: Ok. You can print a line at the beginning of the __init__ showing all the fields in the screen. You can make this with dir(self)